# is there a way to create kanji or other symbol based text fonts using blenders text object?

Tags: workflow, text-object

i'm doing a project where i want to add japanese style text to a mesh but i don't want to make the symbols individually as it will take a while and will most likely not turn out right. preferably a way to convert the english text into japanese kanji or another language much like google translate does.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find an OpenType or Truetype Kanji font, then you can load it into Blender's text object, and paste in your Kanji messaging in *Edit Mode*. You'll have to do the translation part somewhere else though.

If you having issues getting it to work, it might be easier to set the text in another program like [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and then importing the text as SVG file into blender.

Comment: i tested this several times every time i tried to use a truetype or opentype kanji font it was completely invisible except a couple letters which weren't even kanji but instead more like commas. if i was skilled enough at blender i could probably make what i need but it would take an unnecessarily long time

Comment: What font are you using? Is it a font I can download and test?

Comment: cpfont_tt is one of them antique-maru is the other i got them fron a website "www.freejapanesefont.com" at the moment i dont recall which of the two fonts is which one is more of a advertisement style and the other is handwriting style thats the one i was trying to use primarily i believe it is CPfont_tt one though.